# A true large image viewer for OS X?

Tags: applications, photos, image-editing

Are there any image viewers out there that can navigate a truly massive (i.e. 500 megapixel/250MB) JPEG image? Everything but Preview has crashed for me.

Preview does OK, but doesn't have many features.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your requirements are, Preview always does ok for me. However I heard that [Xee](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/xee) is more powerful and some people prefers it.

Comment: Xee is the first one I tried, and it instantly ate up all available RAM and crashed.