# Very large (out of core) image viewer for Mac?

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics, image-editing

(Yes, I've seen [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79679/a-true-large-image-viewer-for-os-x), but what that poster considered  "truly massive" is pretty ordinary now.)

Can anyone suggest an image viewer on the Mac, OSS or commercial, that is capable of displaying TIFF images in the multi-gigabyte range? Ideally something capable of out-of-core viewing, *i.e.*, for images beyond the limits of physical RAM.

I've tried Preview.app (not so much...), ImageMagick (hangs), Adobe Photoshop (worked great on a 25 GB, 8-bit grayscale tiff, 180k x 280k res, on a 16 GB RAM machine, but has a hard resolution limit at 300k in either resolution), and Graphic Converter (did well on a 1.5 GB image, <s>but crashed on an 8 GB one</s> *[Edit: developer fixed this immediately upon my reporting it]*, but cannot open the 25 GB image).

I'm familiar with the old [VLIV](http://delhoume.frederic.free.fr/vliv.htm) on Windows. Anything modern like this for Mac? It doesn't need to be a GUI app, and I have minimal requirements other than that it can actually display the images correctly.

Comment: Have you try with XNViewMP?

Comment: Thanks, tried XNViewMP just now. It was able to open the 1.5 GB image (albeit slowly), but gave an immediate error ("File cannot be loaded!") on the larger images.

Comment: I am also looking for a viewer for the Mar Rover 2.4 GB image. Havent found anything yet

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for the answer to this.

I tried Xee, as recommended on the [linked post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79679/a-true-large-image-viewer-for-os-x), but it could not open the 2.43 GB [~1.8 billion pixel image from NASA's Curiosity rover](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/details.php?id=PIA23623) (88797 x 22958 pixels TIFF image)

I have also tried Phiewer and ApolloOne, but they did not work for me either.

XNViewMP worked for me, but opened the file slowly, and basically freezes when I try to interact with the picture.

Comment: have you tried Phiewer? or ApolloOne?

Comment: Just did, they didn't work either...

Comment: I don't know what format your image is or if you can change it but if so, I'd look for some Astronomy Image viewers. I know the Hubble images got very large,  One such format is FITS, You can search for FITS.viewer.  And there are other Astronomy image viewers.